# Getting tagNames without depending other elements by DOM in javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, domparser

Assume I've this,

```
var sampleString = "<username>user1</username><password>userpassword</password><age>21</age><sex>male</sex>";
```

I'm passing it through DOM parser to fill the data in html form.
I use this as reference.
http://xmljs.sourceforge.net/website/sampleApplications-w3cdom.html

But in this DOM parser

```
docRef.txtFirstName.value = trim(user.getElementsByTagName("FIRSTNAME").item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue(),true, true);
```

Edit : It's converted into a DOM before accessing the above code.  It's filling data in html form by getting values with respect to tagNames one by one, but I need a static method which can be used for filling different forms like getting both tagNames and values onebyone.

They get elements by tagName and fill the form by respective id's. But I've lot of forms in my application. I think it wont be good choice to edit the above code for each and every form. I searched in web to getTagnames, but they all refer to getting tag names from element and so on. I can't find anything related to getting Tagnames from var in javascript. Is it possible to get tagName from var (ofcourse it's a DOM in the final process)?

Comment: No. You have to parse the string value and turn it into a DOM in order to extract from the structure via tag names.

Comment: @Pointy Actully I'm parsing that string and before seperating values by tagNamesm it's a DOM. What I'm asking is, it's filling data in html form by getting values with respect to tagNames one by one, but I need a static method which can be used for filling all forms.

Answer (score 1):

You can just make use of the jQuery's primitive function and then parse it. jQuery function takes a well-formed html string and returns a jQuery object, which has `filter`.

The argument passed to `filter` can be a css-selector.

```
var sampleString = "<username>user1</username><password>userpassword</password><age>21</age><sex>male</sex>";
$(sampleString).filter('username').text(); // user1
```

There are many ways of transversing the DOM in jQuery like `closest`, `find`, `parent`, `filter`, and many more.. Just apply what you need.

Comment: Right, but of course `$(somestring)` is just another way to create a DOM.

Comment: ... and actually in this case I'm not sure it'd work; that string doesn't have a single outer container element. *edit* no I was wrong, it works :)

Comment: @Pointy yup it does :) It just makes DOM of what's given, *temporarily* so it kind of works.

Comment: @Pointy,  "create a DOM" isn't quite the right expression. There's only one DOM per web page. Personally, I would say "create a fragment".

Comment: @Roamer-1888 well I meant "DOM" in the generic sense; *a* Document Object Model, not necessarily *the* Document Object Model. Basically an AST for parsed HTML/XML.

Comment: @Pointy, yes I understand. I'm just being picky.

Comment: It's filling data in html form by getting values with respect to tagNames one by one, but I need a static method which can be used for filling all forms

Comment: I wold not use `$()` to parse something that is not `html` code. I think [jQuery.parseXML](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsexml/) is more suitable:  As `<username>`, `<password>`, ... are not part of the `html` specs there is always a risk that it will break in future if you treat it as html.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use `$.parseHTML(sampleString)` or `$(sampleString)` to parse data that is not valid html. The result might be undefined with future releases of html.

Instead I would make sure that your `sampleString` is a valid xml structure (having only one element at the root):

```
var sampleString = "<info><username>user1</username><password>userpassword</password><age>21</age><sex>male</sex></info>";
```

And parse it using [jQuery.parseXML()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsexml/).
You can use the normal jQuery DOM-Traversing on that result.

```
var doc = $( jQuery.parseXML(sampleString) );
doc.find('username').text();
```

To illustrate the problem with a html tag that is new to html5.
Assume you would like to add the source of information to your data you might use `<source>` as a tag.

```
var sampleString = '<username>user1</username><password>userpassword</password><age>21</age><sex>male</sex><source>form somewhere</source>';
```

If you would use `$.parseHTML(sampleString)` or `$(sampleString)` it would result in:

`[<username>user1</username>, <password>userpassword</password>, <age>21</age><sex>male</sex>, <source>, "from somewhere"]`

As you can see the `"from somewhere"` is not part of `<source>` anymore.